# Installing R in cloudera's hadoop VM

Tags: r, hadoop, cloudera

Using cloudera's distro of hadoop for virtualbox, I first updated the epel:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

Which goes through just fine. But when I try

```
sudo yum install R
```

I get this:

```
Error: Package: R-core-2.15.2-1.e15.x86_64 (epel)
    requires: libtcl8.4.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-2.15.2-1.e15.x86_64 (epel)
    requires: libtk8.4.so() (64bit)
```

And the installation just quits. Is there any recommended steps from here? I get the same errors when trying to open the files from cran as well.

---

edit: I finally figured out the issue. Since I'm new to this kind of thing, I didn't realize the epel-release... file was out of date. If you're blindly following some guide like me and they haven't updated the epel release, you can check by going to http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/ and searching for epel-release. The most current version should be there.

By doing:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

wget http://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-0.97.336-x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install --nogpgcheck rstudio-server-0.97.336-x86_64.rpm
```

That fixed the issue.